Problem with Extracting names of all Pokemon in box-like txt file format
I am looking to parse through a txt file and extract specifically the names of Pokemon as well as their moves and percentages used, in Python, while passing through everything else. A snippet of one pokemon in my txt file is below for reference:
+----------------------------------------+ 
 | Great Tusk                             | 
 +----------------------------------------+ 
 | Raw count: 588311                      | 
 | Avg. weight: 1.0                       | 
 | Viability Ceiling: 91                  | 
 +----------------------------------------+ 
 | Abilities                              | 
 | Protosynthesis 100.000%                | 
 +----------------------------------------+ 
 | Items                                  | 
 | Heavy-Duty Boots 27.301%               | 
 | Booster Energy 22.192%                 | 
 | Leftovers 21.462%                      | 
 | Rocky Helmet 15.298%                   | 
 | Assault Vest  6.317%                   | 
 | Choice Scarf  1.472%                   | 
 | Eject Pack  1.340%                     | 
 | Other  4.618%                          | 
 +----------------------------------------+ 
 | Spreads                                | 
 | Jolly:0/252/0/0/4/252 21.864%          | 
 | Jolly:0/252/4/0/0/252 16.285%          | 
 | Jolly:252/4/0/0/0/252 13.141%          | 
 | Jolly:4/252/0/0/0/252  5.399%          | 
 | Impish:252/0/220/0/0/36  4.399%        | 
 | Adamant:252/252/0/0/4/0  2.986%        | 
 | Other 35.926%                          | 
    
 | Moves                                  | 
 | Rapid Spin 93.632%                     | 
 | Ice Spinner 74.448%                    | 
 | Headlong Rush 69.895%                  | 
 | Knock Off 31.582%                      | 
 | Stealth Rock 30.997%                   | 
 | Close Combat 30.400%                   | 
 | Earthquake 27.250%                     | 
 | Bulk Up 22.838%                        | 
 | Other 18.958%                          | 
 +----------------------------------------+ 
 | Tera Types                             | 
 | Ground 23.792%                         | 
 | Steel 21.370%                          | 
 | Water 11.246%                          | 
 | Fire  9.289%                           | 
 | Poison  8.310%                         | 
 | Ice  8.140%                            | 
 | Ghost  5.585%                          | 
 | Fairy  2.820%                          | 
 | Fighting  2.774%                       | 
 | Grass  2.135%                          | 
 | Other  4.538%                          | 
 +----------------------------------------+ 
 | Teammates                              | 
 | Kingambit 21.019%                      | 
 | Slowking-Galar 20.331%                 | 
 | Gholdengo 19.520%                      | 
 | Dragapult 18.160%                      | 
 | Ogerpon-Wellspring 15.821%             | 
 | Raging Bolt 14.357%                    | 
 | Iron Valiant 11.794%                   | 
 | Iron Crown 11.787%                     | 
 | Dragonite 11.375%                      | 
 | Roaring Moon 11.083%                   | 
 | Iron Moth 11.021%                      | 
 +----------------------------------------+ 
 | Checks and Counters                    | 
 | Sinistcha 81.015 (82.43±0.35)          |
 |   (18.3% KOed / 64.2% switched out)| 
 | Serperior 79.509 (81.71±0.55)          |
 |   (39.9% KOed / 41.8% switched out)| 
 | Iron Valiant 78.810 (79.90±0.27)       |
 |   (40.2% KOed / 39.7% switched out)| 
 | Manaphy 78.606 (82.14±0.88)            |
 |   (42.7% KOed / 39.4% switched out)| 
 | Walking Wake 78.526 (79.89±0.34)       |
 |   (38.7% KOed / 41.2% switched out)| 
 | Comfey 77.023 (81.55±1.13)             |
 |   (36.1% KOed / 45.5% switched out)| 
 | Yanmega 76.370 (82.58±1.55)            |
 |   (51.8% KOed / 30.8% switched out)| 
 | Iron Jugulis 76.151 (82.32±1.54)       |
 |   (49.1% KOed / 33.2% switched out)| 
 | Latias 76.106 (79.93±0.96)             |
 |   (38.9% KOed / 41.0% switched out)| 
 | Ogerpon-Wellspring 75.492 (76.55±0.26) |
 |   (32.4% KOed / 44.2% switched out)| 
 | Enamorus 75.128 (76.42±0.32)           |
 |   (34.7% KOed / 41.8% switched out)| 
 | Cresselia 74.686 (78.51±0.96)          |
 |   (19.2% KOed / 59.3% switched out)| 
 +----------------------------------------+ 

Here is my current algorithm for extracting the txt data to an output file. Right now, it outputs the moves of the respective pokemon and "Moves" above them, but not the names of the Pokemon I am getting the moves from.
with open('text condensed.txt', 'r') as move_text:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
        should_write = False
        for line in move_text:
            if line.startswith('+'):
                next_line = move_text.readline().strip()

                if next_line and not next_line.startswith("|"):
                    out.write(next_line + '\n')
                    print(next_line)
            elif 'Raw count: ' in line:
                should_write = False
            elif 'Moves' in line:
                should_write = True
            elif 'Other' in line:
                should_write = False

            if should_write:
                out.write(line)

When I run the program, my desired output should look something like this:
 Great Tusk
 Moves                                  
 Rapid Spin 93.632%                     
 Ice Spinner 74.448%                   
 Headlong Rush 69.895%                  
 Knock Off 31.582%                      
 Stealth Rock 30.997%                   
 Close Combat 30.400%                   
 Earthquake 27.250%                     
 Bulk Up 22.838% 

 Kingambit                       
 Moves                                  
 Sucker Punch 97.709%                   
 ... 

Instead my actual output looks like this:
 | Moves                                  | 
 | Rapid Spin 93.632%                     | 
 | Ice Spinner 74.448%                    | 
 | Headlong Rush 69.895%                  | 
 | Knock Off 31.582%                      | 
 | Stealth Rock 30.997%                   | 
 | Close Combat 30.400%                   | 
 | Earthquake 27.250%                     | 
 | Bulk Up 22.838%                        | 
 | Moves                                  | 
 | Sucker Punch 97.709%                   |  
...


Sorry, is the problem that this code isn't doing what you expected, or have you just not tried writing the code to do what you want yet? In the first case, please make a [mre] including desired output and actual output; in the second case, what do you need help with? For more tips, check out How to ask a good question. You can [edit] to add details/clarify.

Sorry, I am still new to asking questions on Stack Overflow, I should have clarified that my code isn't getting the expected output. I tried using the above code as well as searching my issue up on Stack Overflow, but I am still having trouble with trying to get my desired result.

One advise here, write what to do in human language first. It should be steps that can easily be followed and which are precise enough to not have to guess. Use that as skeleton to your program. Then, what different types of lines do you have? Write code for each and develop it in isolation, preferably using Test-Driven Development.

@chrischan OK, I see. So there's not actually a question here. For debugging help, read How to debug small programs by Eric Lippert. See also How to step through Python code to help debug issues? Then if you still need help, make a [mre] like I mentioned, using minimal input and the corresponding output (here "Sucker Punch" isn't in the input), and ask a specific question about it.

The problem is your if next_line and not next_line.startswith("|"):... the next_line does start with | (after stripping out the whitespace). In fact, all lines both start and end with a |.
Assuming that the text itself will never contain a |, you can simply replace all those characters with an empty string (before calling .strip()):
line = line.replace('|','')

You also need to out.write an additional blank line either after reading the last move, or before reading the next Pokemon name.
The final code would look something like:
with open('text condensed.txt', 'r') as move_text:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
        should_write = False
        for line in move_text:
            line = line.replace('|','').strip()

            if line.startswith('+'):
                next_line = move_text.readline()

                if next_line:
                    next_line = next_line.replace('|','').strip()
                    out.write(next_line)
            elif 'Raw count: ' in line:
                should_write = False
            elif 'Moves' in line:
                should_write = True
            elif 'Other' in line:
                should_write = False
                out.write('\n')

            if should_write:
                out.write(line)

